# geo: Intent with label (Android)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

Is there a working way (i heard that as of update 7.0 there were some changes) to display a marker with a position given by latitude/longitude with a label?

`geo:?q=latitude, longitude (Label)` does not work...

Comment: you are going to have to be more specific, update 7.0 of what?

Comment: sorry;D of google maps:)

Comment: You might want to keep an eye on this: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/mobile/android-devices/maps-earth-latitude/B7mqPzukV9I

Comment: Thank you:) so there isn't a solution yet is it?

Comment: From the lack of responses there, I'm not sure they see it as a problem, much less have a solution. You have to remember, `geo:` intents are intended for use in many applications, so something that *happens* to work in Google Maps only is a likely target for removal.

Answer (score 6):

Show point on google map via an intent:

```
String uri = "geo:"+ latitude + "," + longitude;

startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri)));
```

You can also choose to place a point like so:

```
String uri = "geo:"+ latitude + "," + longitude + "?q=my+street+address";

startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri)));
```

The Possible Query params options are the following:

- Show map at location: `geo:latitude,longitude`
- Show zoomed map at location: `geo:latitude,longitude?z=zoom`
- Show map at location with point: `geo:0,0?q=my+street+address`
- Show map of businesses in area: `geo:0,0?q=business+near+city`

Comment: thanks for your effort :) .. i know this is from the documentation, but the one i was using before was this : String uri = "geo:"+ latitude + "," + longitude + "?q=my+street+address";

Problem is that this only searches for the "my+street+adress"-part and therefore is far more unaccurate than the gps-data

Comment: Try to open GPS after starting Activity and if you are using the emulator you should semilate the latitude,longitude.and what is the update 7.0??

Comment: I don't exactly know what you mean... I'm using a real device with gps enabled (galaxy s3) ... but my issue has nithing to do with the gps sensor of my phone, does it?

Comment: You can try to use this code for Map v2

http://bon-app-etit.blogspot.be/2012/12/add-informationobject-to-marker-in.html

Comment: Problem is that this doesn't use an intent rather than using a fragment which i have to implement in my app ;D .. But i might use this in the future anyways ;D

Comment: A question, can i add by query a .kml file route with this method?

Comment: Important bit, "geo:latitude,longitude" will not create a point on map. For that you need to write coordinates in the query part. For example: "geo:?q=latitude,longitude"

Comment: Thanks @AndrazP, using `geo:lat,long?q=blah` performed a query search for me and listed the results, it did not show the location with a pin. AndrazP comment is correct, this should be `geo:?q=lat,long` to show a point on the map