# maps intent geo:0,0?q=latitude,longitude(label) returns "results not found"

Tags: android-intent, maps

I've started to get complaints from my users about maps instance, launched from my app, resulting in "no results found". I noticed that after the last update of maps ( I dont keep up to date in maps versin), if i try to launch using the intent geo:latitude,longitude?q=latitude,longitude(label), though it will center the map correctly, it will display result not found for most of south america and a few countries on Europe. The strangest thing is that the map activity shows that it is searching for "latitude, longitude". If i manually change the search string to "latitude,longitude" (blank removed) it will find the location. Where should i report this ? The blank is inserted by the intent itself.

If you want to test it, open google maps , and search for example "-23.612, -46.882" and after that search  "-23.612,-46.882" and it will work.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like, despite being documented [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps), you can't rely on the `(label)`.  I initially got a report from our QA team that was testing on `Google Maps 6.12.0`.  After some testing and research I found a lot of reports about problems, including the following:

- [Forum post on Waze](https://www.waze.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=657&t=107536)
- [Comments on an SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7405992/1747491)
- [Another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18724436/1747491)
- [Google Code issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8050)

Answer (score 0):

You can workaround it adding quotes around the location.

Something like this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=\""+latitude+","+longitude+"\"");
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(intent);
```

But you lost the capability of setting a tag label. Tell me if you found a way to add it too.